# Unable to read Riverpod provider in web app . throgh Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutterwebviewplugin

I have an app that i want to build for web but when i try to run login function the auth provider throgh a error

**"Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'**

this happen only in web.

here is my authrepo provider

```
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider<AuthRepositoryImpl>(
  (ref) => AuthRepositoryImpl(apiServices: ref.read(dioServiceProvider)),
);
```

and i am reading the provider with this code

```
 final authRepo = ref.read(authRepositoryProvider)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the error happens along the way
`packages/kezo/ui/auth/login.dart 110:29`

It is in this place that you need to understand why it happens. You should probably check your value against `null` instead of using forced cast via `as`. This can be done through the simplest `if (value != null)`, or use `as String?`

Comment: got it acutllay the fcm token is null that is why it cause error thanks for the quick response

Comment: Also, pattern matching is a lot more compact and yet robust for decoding API calls now.